# ASP.NET UpdatePanels not updating correctly

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

I have two panels on my page.  When the first panel is updated the code for the first panel is executed.  When the second panel is updated (text changed) the code for the first panel is executed.  I can click the button for the second panel and execute the right code, but why won't the correct trigger fire when the second panel is changed?

Tried this on both Windows Server 2008R2 and Windows 7 IIS on Development machine.

```
TESTPANEL.ASPX

<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="testpanel.aspx.vb" Inherits="tpanels.testpanel" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
      <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btn1" Text="BTN1" OnClick="btn1_click" />
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="BTN2" Text="BTN2" OnClick="btn2_Click" />
      <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="pnl1" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="False">
        <ContentTemplate>
          <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt1" value="start"></asp:TextBox>
          <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt2" value="start"></asp:TextBox>
        </ContentTemplate>

      </asp:UpdatePanel>
      <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="pnl2" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="False">
        <ContentTemplate>
          <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt3" value="start"></asp:TextBox>
          <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt4" value="start"></asp:TextBox>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
          <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="BTN2"  EventName="click" />
        </Triggers>
      </asp:UpdatePanel>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

TESTPANEL.ASPX.VB

```
Public Class testpanel
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
  Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

  End Sub

  Protected Sub BTN2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    txt4.Text = txt3.Text
  End Sub

  Protected Sub btn1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    txt2.Text = txt1.Text
  End Sub
End Class
```